# PC not working properly

Tags: windows-7

My pc is not working properly.When I am clicking on "My computer" icon its not opening. I had tried all possible ways of opening "My computer" but still unable to open. How can I open "My Computer".Please help

Comment: Unfortunately If you have already tried all possible ways of opening it we wouldn't be able to recommend anything you haven't tried

Comment: Do other things work? What exactly happens when you click on the icon? Did it ever work? If so, what changed between when it was working and when it wasn't? You have to give us something to go on.

Comment: Can you open the Taskmanager and end all explorer.exe-Processes? Then open in the Taskmanager Menu "File" "New Task" a new Task explorer.exe and try again.
does this help?

Answer (score 2):

Try restarting your PC. If that doesn't do it then right-click your taskbar and start the task manager. Go to the 'processes' tab and find 'explorer.exe.' Click it once and press the 'End Process' button on the bottom right side of the window. Please try this and reply.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, this must be a virus infection. Use any good Antivirus. I recommend Kaspersky

By the time...To access your data,

> Press Windows key + R ......
>   Type any drive letter , Say C://
>
> Press Enter.

Comment me what happens.